# Run an external command and get the amount of CPU it consumed

Tags: python

Pretty simple, I'd like to run an external command/program from within a Python script, once it is finished I would also want to know how much CPU time it consumed.

Hard mode: running multiple commands in parallel won't cause inaccuracies in the CPU consumed result.

Comment: Does this have to be multiplatform? If not, which OS is this supposed to run on? Most operating systems provide access to different timers, but the most accurate ones might require elevated privileges.

Comment: Just Linux is fine, Windows compatibility is appreciated but unnecessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**On UNIX:** either (a) use [resource](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) module (also see answer by icktoofay), or (b) use the [time](http://linux.die.net/man/7/time) command and parse the results, or (c) use [/proc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem, parse /proc/[pid]/stat and parse out `utime` and `stime` fields.  The last of these is Linux-specific.

Example of using `resource`:

```
import subprocess, resource
usage_start = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
subprocess.call(["yourcommand"])
usage_end = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
cpu_time = usage_end.ru_utime - usage_start.ru_utime
```

Note: it is not necessary to do fork/execvp, `subprocess.call()` or the other [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) methods are fine here and much easier to use.

Note: you could run multiple commands from the same python script simultaneously either using subprocess.Popen or subprocess.call and threads, but resource won't return their correct individual cpu times, it will return the sum of their times in between calls to getrusage; to get the individual times, run one little python wrapper per command to time it as above (could launch those from your main script), or use the `time` method below which *will* work correctly with multiple simultaneous commands (time is basically just such a wrapper).

Example of using `time`:

```
import subprocess, StringIO
time_output = StringIO.StringIO()
subprocess.call(["time", "yourcommand", "youroptions"], stdout=time_output)
# parse time_output
```

**On Windows:** You need to use performance counters (aka "performance data helpers") somehow.  Here is a [C example](http://en.literateprograms.org/CPU_usage_using_performance_counters_%28C,_Windows_2000%29) of the underlying API.  To get it from python, you can use one of two modules: [win32pdh](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32pdh.html) (part of pywin32; [sample code](http://www.cac.cornell.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Performance_Data_Helper_in_Python_with_win32pdh)) or [pyrfcon](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfcon/) (cross-platform, also works on Unix; [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfcon/source/browse/trunk/example.py)).

Any of these methods actually meet the "hard mode" requirements above: they should be accurate even with multiple running instances of different processes on a busy system.  They may not produce the exact same results in that case compared to running just one process on an idle system, because process switching does have some overhead, but they will be very close, because they ultimately get their data from the OS scheduler.

Comment: +1 with the remark that using `/proc` in this way is specific to Linux.

Answer (score 4):

On platforms where it's available, [the `resource` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) may provide what you need. If you need to time multiple commands simultaneously, you may want to (for each command you want to run) [fork](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork) and then create the subprocess so you get information for only that process. Here's one way you might do this:

```
def start_running(command):
    time_read_pipe, time_write_pipe = os.pipe()
    want_read_pipe, want_write_pipe = os.pipe()
    runner_pid = os.fork()
    if runner_pid != 0:
        os.close(time_write_pipe)
        os.close(want_read_pipe)
        def finish_running():
            os.write(want_write_pipe, 'x')
            os.close(want_write_pipe)
            time = os.read(time_read_pipe, struct.calcsize('f'))
            os.close(time_read_pipe)
            time = struct.unpack('f', time)[0]
            return time
        return finish_running
    os.close(time_read_pipe)
    os.close(want_write_pipe)
    sub_pid = os.fork()
    if sub_pid == 0:
        os.close(time_write_pipe)
        os.close(want_read_pipe)
        os.execvp(command[0], command)
    os.wait()
    usage = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
    os.read(want_read_pipe, 1)
    os.write(time_write_pipe, struct.pack('f', usage.ru_utime))
    sys.exit(0)
```

You can then use it to run a few commands:

```
get_ls_time = start_running(['ls'])
get_work_time = start_running(['python', '-c', 'print (2 ** 512) ** 200'])
```

After that code has executed, both of those commands should be running in parallel. When you want to wait for them to finish and get the time they took to execute, call the function returned by `start_running`:

```
ls_time = get_ls_time()
work_time = get_work_time()
```

Now `ls_time` will contain the time `ls` took to execute and `work_time` will contain the time `python -c "print (2 ** 512) ** 200"` took to execute.

Answer (score 3):

You can do timings within Python, but if you want to know the overall CPU consumption of your program, that is kind of silly to do. The best thing to do is to just use the GNU `time` program. It even comes standard in most operating systems.

Comment: I want to run this command programmatically from within a Python script, I made my question a bit clearer. I want to be able to get the result of the command as well as the amount of CPU time it used.

Answer (score 2):

The [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module of python is very useful for benchmarking/profiling purposes. In addtion to that you can even call it from the command-line interface. To benchmark a external command, you would go like this:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("call(['ls','-l'])",setup="from subprocess import call",number=1) #number defaults to 1 million
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nilanjan nilanjan 3675 Dec 17 08:23 icon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nilanjan nilanjan  279 Dec 17 08:24 manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nilanjan nilanjan  476 Dec 17 08:25 popup.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nilanjan nilanjan 1218 Dec 17 08:25 popup.js
0.02114391326904297
```

The last line is the returned execution time. Here, the first argument to `timeit.timeit()` is the code for calling the external method and `setup` argument specifies the code to run before the start of time-measurement. `number` argument is the number of time you wish to run the specified code and then you can divide the time returned by the `number` to get average time.

You can also use the `timeit.repeat()` method which takes similar arguments as `timeit.timeit()` but takes an additional `repeat` argument to specify the number of time `timeit.timeit()` should be called and returns a list of execution times for each run.

**Note**: The execution time returned by the `timeit.timeit()` method is the wall clock time, not the CPU time. So, other processes may interfere with the timing. So, in case of `timeit.repeat()` you should take the minimum value instead of trying to calculate the average or standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ipython's [`%time` magic function](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html#IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.time):

```
In [1]: time 2**128
CPU times: user 0.00 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 0.00 s
Wall time: 0.00
Out[1]: 340282366920938463463374607431768211456L

In [2]: n = 1000000

In [3]: time sum(range(n))
CPU times: user 1.20 s, sys: 0.05 s, total: 1.25 s
Wall time: 1.37
Out[3]: 499999500000L
```