# get how much time python subprocess spends

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to time how long does the subprocess take.
I tried to use

```
start = time.time()
subprocess.call('....')
elapsed = (time.time() - start)
```

However it's not very accurate (not sure related to multi-process or sth else)
Is there a better way I can get how much time the subprocess really spends?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on which time you want; elapsed time, user mode, system mode?

With [`resource.getrusage`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) you can query the user mode and system mode time of the current process's children. This only works on UNIX platforms (like e.g. Linux, BSD and OS X):

```
import resource
info = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
```

On Windows you'll probably have to use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to get equivalent information from the WIN32 API.

Comment: this answer looks fine for timing python code, but if we are running a subprocess, this may not be accurate, since Popen.wait() uses a busy loop. [https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait]

Comment: @ggg Not sure if this is really a problem: Popen.wait() should run in the current process. Therefore, the resource usage of child processes should not be affected.

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13933797/6196010) is quite more explicit about how to go about this.

Answer (score 7):

This is more accurate:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit(stmt = "subprocess.call('...')", setup = "import subprocess", number = 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

It took me a little while to implement Roland's solution due to the annoyingness of passing around python code as strings, so I thought I'd share a working example.

This script times an external program in the working directory, and redirects its standard output and standard error to files.

```
from timeit import timeit

reps = 500
stdout = open("add_numbers_outputs.log", 'w')
stderr = open("add_numbers_errors.log", 'w')
external_command = "./add_numbers"
parameter = str(1000000) # one million

call_arguments = """[
        '%s',
        '%s'], # pass additional parameters by adding elements to this list
        stdout=stdout,
        stderr=stderr
""" % (external_command, parameter)

print "Timing external command "+external_command+" with parameter "+parameter

time_taken = timeit(stmt = "subprocess.call(%s)" % call_arguments,
        setup = """import subprocess;
stdout = open("add_numbers_outputs.log", 'w');
stderr = open("add_numbers_errors.log", 'w')
""",
        number = reps) / reps

print "Average time taken for %s repetitions: %f seconds" % (reps, time_taken)
```

Comment: If it would make your code easier, you can pass a function to `timeit()` and avoid having to put any Python code inside of strings.